# How to find the "Handle" to a Service in the UI part of an application OR better way of writing the main Activity

Tags: java, android, service

I writing an app the contains a Service to perform work. The main Activity has an UI that is updated with a Message passed during creation of the Service. My problem is that during the initial creation of the Service by the main Activity, the message handler is valid and reports messages from the Service fine. If I press the "Back" or "Home" button, the main Activity seems to be discarded but the Service is still executing.

Finally, when I bring the app up again, I can tell the Service is running (since its communicating over bluetooth to hardware) but the handle to the UI updater is not valid anymore and the app does not receive status updates.

So, is there a way to get the "handle" or "Intent" of the Service so I can pass it the new message handler OR is there a better way of "classing" the main Activity so it does not get destroyed.

Comment: Make use of some static variable that holds the instance of the Activity. Or make use of `volatile`.

Comment: bind service each time in oncreate

Comment: I cant seem to use a static var as the handler interacts with the layout. I'll have to read up more on Binding, as Im fairly new to android and java programming.

Comment: I bound the service to the activity following http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. This allows the task to run and the ability to receive messages when the main activity is ran in foreground again w/o crashing. 

Now the problem is that the textview control never changes even though Im sending textview.setText with status.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps or if you are doing this verify again

1. onbind()-->returns ibinder;
2. extend a class called Binder ,override the method return this service reference from there.
3. make a utitlity method say : getText inside your service that returns data from the service
4. implement serviceconnection interface in your main activity override two methods on service connected/disconnected

5.on serviceconnected -> using the ibinder object call getService method cast it back to your service.

1. so now that you have your service object via the above step now you can call getText method of your service inside your main activity and so you can say --**String text_returned=your_service.getText()** set this text wherever you want to.

i hope it helps.

Comment: how can you change an activity to service?

Comment: You can't change an activity into a service but you can make a service interact with the activity by calling bindservice rather than startservice.that's what i meant in my answer above.

Comment: what i mean is how i can transform my activity gps tracking location to a service tracking location.i was told that in order for your activity to work on background it should be a service.

Comment: You need to run it in background changing few things 1. extends Service class rather than an Activity class 2. override service methods like oncreate onDestroy onBind ,onstartCommand 3.change the activity tag in manifest to service tag so that will convert it into service now